# Unity keeps giving me this error code but it worked before?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
It is a basic Camera trigger code supposed to be used on cinemachine fixed still shots
worked last year and now it no longer works?

Is there something wrong with my code or is unity going crazy? or am i going crazy?

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;
using System.Media;

public class ShotZone : MonoBehaviour
{
    CinemachineVirtualCamera currentCamera;
    Player player;

    public CinemachineVirtualCamera targetCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
    }


    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            SceneChange();
        }
    }

    void SceneChange()
    {
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera") != null)
        {
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera<() != null)
            {
                currentCamera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentCamera = null;
        }

        if (currentCamera != targetCamera || currentCamera == null) ;
        {
            targetCamera.tag = "CurrentCamera";
            targetCamera.Priority = 100;

            currentCamera.tag = "InactiveCamera";
            currentCamera.Priority = 99;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: semi-colon typo on line `if (currentCamera != targetCamera || currentCamera == null) ;`

Comment: what line of code does the error complain about?

Comment: It was complaining about line 31

Comment: if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera<() != null)

this is what it was complaining about

Comment: you're missing a `>` to close the generic definition on that line. like `if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera<>() != null)`

Comment: I now made line 31:
if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>() != null)

and it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line that is wrong- a simple typo. You're missing a > at the following line

```cs
if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera<() != null) { }
```

It should be like this

```cs
if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CurrentCamera").GetComponent<CinemachineVirtualCamera>() != null) { }
```